# Opening Geberit flush button

Tags: plumbing, water, toilet

I'm trying to open this Geberit flush button in order to put anti calcarium tabs inside it, but I don't know how to.

It slides a little bit to both sides and up and down, but there's no demonstration it will open and I'm afraid to break it. How can I open it in order to have access to the water?

Thank you!

[image: Geberit flush button]

Comment: I have only ever worked on 1 and if I am following you those are the flush controls. The one I worked on had 2 buttons one for a dump and 1 for a pee.       The other controls were for the water temp and mist or spray. I don’t think they are designed for things to be added to the tank it is enclosed or the one I was called to fix the tank was enclosed and the warm water tank had a hatch for the heater access. Not for adding chemicals. If you add the brand and model someone more knowledgeable may be able to help.

Comment: @EdBeal thank you! The only thing I know this is an Geberit valve with concealed cistern. I tried to find it on Geberit catalogue and I wasn't able to. Anyway I need to open it to solve a hiss issue.
Thank you for any other ideas!